# What do NSLocalizedString() parameters "value" and "tableName" do?

Tags: ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

The Apple docs for this (both in Xcode and webpage) have exactly *no* explanation of the parameters.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring

For reference, the function signature is

```
NSLocalizedString(
    _ key    : String, 
    tableName: String? = default,  // ??
    bundle   : Bundle = default, 
    value    : String = default,   // ????
    comment  : String
) -> String
```

I have a vague idea what the `tableName` is -- but more information would be helpful. (Is it merely the filename for a strings file?) I have no idea what `value` is for.

Comment: Please read the documentation of [`Bundle`'s localizedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1417694-localizedstring)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Objective-C documentation for `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue` explains the parameters:

> ## Parameters
>
> **key**
> The key for a string in the specified table.
>
> **tableName**
> The name of the table containing the key-value pairs. Also, the suffix for the strings file (a file with the .strings extension) to store the localized string.
>
> **bundle**
> The bundle containing the strings file.
>
> **value**
> The value to return if key is nil or if a localized string for key can’t be found in the table.
>
> **comment**
> The comment to place above the key-value pair in the strings file.

Basically, the `key` is looked up in a file named `tableName.strings` in the specified bundle. That strings file will have the format:

```
# comment
"key" = "value"
```

Comment: Yep, just found it too. Thanks. Though one would think the actual underlying function would be documented. Now I just have to worry about word-order, plurals, placeholders, etc. We're doing Arabic and Mandarin...